# What is the proper way to dispose of a complex data structure?

Tags: java

I have a rather complex data structure that is stacks Map structures inside other maps:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, PerformanceScopeMeta> > complex;
```

Here is the PerformanceScopeMeta class:

```
class PerformanceScopeMeta {
    /* Meta information */
    private Map<String, String> meta;
    private List<PerformanceMessage> messages;
 }
```

This is what I do to "make the memory available for garbage collection" :

```
complex.put("SOME_KEY", null);
```

Is that enough or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if nothing *else* has a reference to the map, then yes, that's enough (assuming your map accepts null values).

But bear in mind that if the object that `complex` refers to becomes eligible for garbage collection, then you don't need to do anything at all. It's only if you need to clear part of the map that you need to do this. It's relatively rare that you have to do *anything* for the sake of the garbage collector, in my experience.

Personally I'd use `Map.remove` instead of your suggested code though:

```
complex.remove("SOME_KEY");
```

You don't *really* want an entry with a null value, I assume... you just want to get rid of the entry altogether, right?

Comment: I want the data structure to clear it's memory eventually, so removing the top referencing key is enough I guesss.

Comment: @code-gijoe: But is `complex` itself going to be eligible for garbage collection? If so, you don't need to remove each of the bits from it.

Comment: I is a member of a singleton (unfortunately) running at server startup, that is why I need to know the memory will be freed.

Comment: @code-gijoe: Okay - so yes, that should be fine,  but I'd suggest you start working out how to remove the singleton. Also, be careful about the threading aspect... most maps aren't thread-safe, and most singletons are accessed from multiple threads.

Answer (score 4):

use `complex.remove("SOME_KEY")` is OK if the removed value or any objects in that removed map are not referenced by any of your code.

Answer (score 4):

To remove a key from the map, use `complex.remove("SOME_KEY")`. This will make the corresponding value eligible for garbage collection, *provided there are no remaining live references to it*.